# How does Windows decide whether to trigger MouseUp or Click?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I have a control with some complex dragging functionality.  It is also clickable.

I'm finding that sometimes a click (rapid mouse down-up, no movement) results in an `OnMouseUp` event, sometimes a `Click` event.  This appears to be timing dependent...if I put breakpoints on the `MouseDown` event, I get `Click`, otherwise I get (mainly) `OnMouseUp`.

So how does Windows decide which event to trigger?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is timing dependent.  If you click fast enough then you get a DoubleClick event instead.  You probably already knew that :)  You can turn that off, reset the ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick style.

Comment: DoubleClick?  Is that when you click with both hands?  Being serious, it's not seeing double-clicks, I'm just doing one click and then seeing which breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mouse click should trigger both events.  See [Mouse Events in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx) for details, but (from the documentation):

> All Windows Forms controls raise click events in the same order when a mouse button is pressed and released (regardless of which mouse button), except where noted in the following list for individual controls. The following list shows the order of events raised for a single mouse-button click:
>
> MouseDown event.
>
> Click event.
>
> MouseClick event.
>
> MouseUp event.

Note that some controls have different behavior (documented in individual controls), and the double click behavior is a bit different, as well (also documented [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx)).

Also - putting break points in the debugger can cause the message processing behavior to occasionally get a bit strange.  I would recommend using `Debug.WriteLine` or a similar methodology to trace all of the output through the individual messages instead of using breakpoints, if you want to see all of the messages get processed in order.